# How to histogram one dimensional data in r?

Tags: r

If `x` is one dimensional data like this`x=c(43,56,33,67,34,66,78,34)` then how I get the histogram of `x`. I know that histogram requires a frequency. But how about in this case?

Comment: Maybe `hist(x)` ?

Comment: I tried it but the plot doesn't appear at all!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `hist(x)` what you need? or tell me more details.

Comment: I tried hist(x) but I cannot see the plot at all. There is no error message.

Comment: Hhhhhh. I am so sorry. Yes, I open a separate window. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest doing your R-code for file manipulation and plotting in Rstudio. Rstudio makes managing plots so much simpler as you can easily save and refer to plots without retyping the plot commands to make the prior plot.